# POST Requests Randomly Dropped when Using Apache Over SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, centos7

I'm having just about the same issue as [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/745841/web-server-resets-post-request-randomly-when-going-over-ssl). However, I'm on CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4.6. My site is on Wordpress.

Sometimes when I, or another user, submits a form, the browser will say that the connection was unexpectedly dropped by the server.

I've been able to find very little about this on Google. On the browser end, I've heard that deleting cookies and other website data helps, but I want to know how to prevent this issue for other users.

This is on SSL, as well. Here is my SSL configuration:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName cocreationcoaching.org:443

ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

SSLHonorCipherOrder on 
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; preload"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
SSLCompression off 
SSLUseStapling on 

SSLCertificateFile /root/cocreationcoaching.org.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cocreationcoaching.org.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cocreationcoaching.org.ca-bundle

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the server error log when this happens? The parser of wordpress is php, yet there is nothing of it shown in the question? Have you enabled error logs in it and review them too? The configuration you show tells little and nothing in it seems wrong, so if you don't have a networking issue of some sort, chances are there can be something odd going on with php.

Comment: No, nothing in the error log, either for Apache or PHP.

Comment: Also, how does the configuration seem wrong? And, I didn't include PHP because I've seen this issue elsewhere and Apache + SSL was the common denominator, just as in the issue I linked to in my question.

Comment: I said "NOTHING IN IT seems wrong" :)

Comment: Oops, sorry. Misread. :)

Comment: Have you compared packet captures from client and server to verify that all packets are being delivered without corruption.

Comment: This hasn't happened further after the last incident, so I'm hoping it was a temporary fluke.

Comment: You also can check for network issues like dropped packets